# how to install SSL certificate on azure scale set?

Tags: azure

Need to know how can I Install SSL certificate on a scale set on azure ?
I will deploy a scale set with 2 instances , load balancer & azure firewall

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096471/adding-certificates-to-azure-vm-scale-set?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really experienced in scale sets, but based on this page: [SSL enabled VM Scale Set](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-vmss-ubuntu-web-ssl/) I suspect that it is possible using arm templates. The page links to the [Azure Quickstart Templates](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/201-vmss-ubuntu-web-ssl/azuredeploy.json). Using `certThumbPrint` you can point to a certificate in your Azure Keyvault.

Since most features of arm templates are also available in the portal, I suspect that you can also point to a Keyvault from the portal.

(I'm new to the (active) community, so I'm open to suggestions how to help as efficient / good as possible.)